# hooks adapting react web to react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

This is my react web hooks example:

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('...')
  const [name, setName] = useState('')

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={e=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        if(!value.length) { return false }
        setName(value)
      }}>
        <input type="text" value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}></input>
      </form>
      
      <p>mi llamo {value}</p>
      <p> name : {name}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

And now my adaptation, that is not working for react native, what to use on the form part?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput
  } from 'react-native';

function Hooking() {

    const [value, setValue] = useState('..')
    const [name, setName] = useState('')

    console.log("sasasa")
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput style={{borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1}}
                value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Text>mi llamo: {value}</Text>
            <Text>name: {value}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Hooking;
```

So how to adapt my above code to work on react native? cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onChangeText in React-native

onChangeText={text => setValue(text)}

Comment: hi, I get: `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: Opps..  onChangeText={text => setValue(text)}